# Preparing data for modulation classification based on RML2016

Tags: modulation, classification

I would like to validate a trained model based on RML2016.10a. My idea is to capture a certain amount of data (20 Msps) for approximately 0.3 seconds. Then, I identify all the signals in this bandwidth (I know their frequency and bandwidth). Next, I would like to feed these signals one by one into the model and classify their modulation. What preprocessing do I need to perform on each signal for my model to correctly interpret it? I have data in both the time and frequency domains

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess it so that it "looks like" the training data. If you did trained using raw baseband signal then use that as input, if you did some filtering or other operations to the raw signal beforehand then you should match that before passing to your model. In my experience, things can be finicky if you start giving signals that had undergone different preprocessing steps.

Comment: This is a dataset with artificially generated signals https://www.deepsig.ai/datasets. With a bandwidth of 1 Msps. I receive a signal with the same sample rate. And I filter them according to the bandwidth of the input signal

Comment: . But I constantly detect the same modulation. I think that the problem is in data normalization. And I don't understand how to normalize them.

Comment: Different normalization would fall under my experience of things being finicky when different preprocessing had been applied